# Bundle size is big

Tags: ios, skmaps

Is there a way to reduce the size of the framework **ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK**, because right now the size of the bundle is so huge and the user probably won't download an app with >100 Mb.

Comment: See  http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/6682-Bundle-Size-is-big

Answer (score 3):

For people who are interested:

To minimizing the size of the project you can do the following:
Benchmark: demo project unpacked – 173.883.119 bytes (195,7 MB on disk)

Things that can be removed for iOS:
1.  Remove all audio advices but en_us from SKAdvisorResources.bundle (Note: you can host & download the audio files on demand)
2.  Remove Outdoorstyle and Grayscale style from SkMaps.bundle (if you're not using these syles)
Demo project unpacked - 115.890.904 bytes (118,5 MB on disk) 
3.  Remove all other architectures but armv7 (there should be a small performance penalty on arm64, but since you exclude an entire set of architectures the size of the .ipa should be considerable smaller) - this change will be visible in the final .ipa file

Things that can be removed for Android:
On Android you can repeat steps 1 and 2.
Regarding architectures – if you have control regarding which Android devices you will be using, you can also remove the unused libraries (we have by default /libs/armeabi/libsngnative.so, /libs/armeabi-v7a/libsnative.so and /libs/x86/libsnative.so)

These are the things that can be done for the moment to decrease the size- but we're still working on this improvement for the next versions

Comment: Thanks for the above is there any improvements that were made since this post ?