# SKMaps Bundle size is big

Tags: android, skmaps

I read on how to reduce SKMaps.zip file size by deleting some of the files. Regarding to the same I need more information.

I deleted grayscalestyle, outdoorstyle and nightstyle folders and all the contents of sound_files (Maps/Advisor/en) directory.

There are two folders .Common and .Routing, .Common is of 28.5MB!! Are all the contents of this directory required? I tried deleting these two folders completely which resulted in map crash. If can be deleted which all files in these two folders can be deleted?

PreInstalledMaps directory is >10MB, which files can be deleted from this? I don't have preinstalled maps feature at all.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982941/bundle-size-is-big), I need much more clarifications WRT other directories. Please let me know which all directories/files can be deleted as I need to reduce final APK size as much as possible.

No Routing/directions in this app.

Answer (score 2):

The common directory contains files shared by all styles - the biggest file in there is the fonts file.

The fonts file provides all the required glyphs for all the character sets that the SDK supports (latin, arabic, cyrillic, chinese, etc.) - for the time being you cannot delete anything in there. In a future update there will be the option to use system fonts (instead of a fonts file).

The only workaround (at this time) would be to separate this file from the bundle, host it on your servers and download it before starting the SDK - this will be a one time operation - it will reduces the initial app size but it will increase the startup time (the first time).

The PreInstalledMaps folder - you can delete the meta folder.

Comment: Thank you Ando. I deleted meta folder in PreInstalledMaps. Can you guide me the font files of non-English languages, because we are not supporting as of now. If saving .zip file in an external storage work when downloaded during runtime. As I checked, library was expecting the zip file in assets folder.

Comment: Ando, What about the .tex files in .Common folder? Please let me know about this too.

Comment: Those are the "texture" files - on lower zoom levels (globe view) we don't render the map using vector graphics but just display some textures - it's faster this way. You can delete the .tex files, but then make sure that the user won't be able to zoom out past a certain zoom level, otherwise the sdk will go looking for those .tex files

Comment: Thanks Ando. I deleted .tex files which resulted in not displaying place/street names. Is missing .tex files reason?

Comment: No - removing the .tex files will just cause the SDK to crash on low zoom levels (if not handled properly). Another change is to blame for missing place/street names (maybe fonts?)

Comment: Yes. I deleted "uni*.ttf" font because file size was relatively big than all others. I will add it back to the .zip file.

Comment: So, deleting all the .tex files will not result in SDK crash if zoom levels are handled properly. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes - I'll have to check if there is any programmatic way of forcing the SDK to only show the map from zoom level 5 or more (but I'll only be able to do this next year :) ). Until then you'll have to handle this scenario yourself

Comment: Haha Okay Ando. Even I will also look into this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @Ando any update on using system font ? Using SKMap version 2.5.2 and bundle still has font files like unifont_512.ttf (size ~16 MB). Is it safe to delete unifont_512.ttf file ? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi @gopal - no developments in this area - the unifot_512 file is still required.

Comment: Hi @Ando I tried running app by removing unifont_512 file and haven't seen odd behavior/crash. Do you know what issues I can expect if unifont_512 file not added ? It will be helpful if you know what issues to expect. Are they minor or major ? Thanks again for your help and a quick reply.

Comment: The unifont file contains all the fonts used for map label - I'm actually not sure what would happen if you were to remove the file - I expect it to crash. You can try to edit the style file to use everywhere the same font - this would give you the possibility of "trimming" down unused fonts from the fonts file.
In your particular test make sure that you are doing a clear reinstall of your app - just to make sure that the new SKMaps.zip is unpacked and used

Comment: @Ando thanks for the tip it really helped and worked. Do you have any other suggestions ? What about "worldL2.tex" file (~2 MB) ?

Comment: The .tex files can be deleted but then make sure that you never zoom to lower than zoom level 4 as the .tex files are only used in zoom levels below zoom level 4