# Downloading SKMaps.zip separately

Tags: android, skmaps

Is there a way of downloading SKMaps.zip separately, and not include it in the assets folder of the main APK?

The reason for this is purely to reduce the size of the APK. Our application is distributed privately to customers over a mobile connection (WiFi is not an option), and SKMaps.zip is currently occupying about 24MB of the 37MB of our app. Reducing the app size will save us huge amounts of money in bandwidth fees.

Answer (score 1):

SKMaps.zip is the resource folder where you can find all the images or other resources used by the SDK and needs to be in the asset folder.
For the offline scenarios, the only mandatory file is the .skm. The .ngi an .ngi.dat are used only for searches, and the textures are used for better display of a country on a high zoom level- so you can delete these two if you don't need them.

Other ways to win some space: 
http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/6682-Bundle-Size-is-big and 
[SKMaps Bundle size is big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590673/skmaps-bundle-size-is-big)